# devextreme datagrid when ı manupulation in lookup data. my daragrid is state column not working

Tags: angular, devextreme

when ı manupulation my state list
datagrid is not working because I change in lookup data.

**if u want to test my problem.**

look at my codesandbox and insert new value

```
 logEvent(eventName) {
  // here 
this.states = this.states.filter((x) => x.ID === 5);

this.events.unshift(eventName);
```

}

link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/row-editing-and-editing-events-devextreme-data-grid-forked-z21ixv?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Also share screenshots and more description on what's wrong and what needs to be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I want to my last data dont go on.

also when ı delete items in lookup.

I want to do not manipulation in datagrid.

[first - be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnVsp.jpg)

[second -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o812U.png)

[my change code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blktG.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).